# On call of wcf webservice method gives error IllegalArgumentException: size <= 0

Tags: java, android, wcf, base64, ksoap2

In my application i am calling a wcf webservice method for sending images through base 64... On call of that method i am getting an error as :

```
03-17 12:02:13.187: W/System.err(5822): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: size <= 0
03-17 12:02:13.195: W/System.err(5822):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.<init>(BufferedInputStream.java:94)
03-17 12:02:13.195: W/System.err(5822):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:226)
03-17 12:02:13.195: W/System.err(5822):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:114)
03-17 12:02:13.195: W/System.err(5822):     at com.android.lntproject.SOAPWebservice.Base64ToImage(SOAPWebservice.java:982)
03-17 12:02:13.195: W/System.err(5822):     at com.android.mobescan.ImageUtils.getCompressedImagePath(ImageUtils.java:119)
03-17 12:02:13.195: W/System.err(5822):     at com.android.mobescan.HomeActivity$UploadScan.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:537)
03-17 12:02:13.195: W/System.err(5822):     at com.android.mobescan.HomeActivity$UploadScan.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:1)
03-17 12:02:13.195: W/System.err(5822):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-17 12:02:13.195: W/System.err(5822):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-17 12:02:13.203: W/System.err(5822):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-17 12:02:13.203: W/System.err(5822):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-17 12:02:13.203: W/System.err(5822):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-17 12:02:13.203: W/System.err(5822):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-17 12:02:13.210: W/System.err(5822):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

The method is written as :

```
public SoapPrimitive Base64ToImage(String base64String, String imgName) {
    SoapPrimitive result = null;

    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/",
                "Base64ToImage");

        request.addProperty("base64String", base64String);
        request.addProperty("imgName", imgName);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);// soap envelop with version
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); // set request object
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url1);// http
                                                                        // transport
                                                                        // call
        androidHttpTransport.call(
                "http://tempuri.org/IService/Base64ToImage", envelope);

        // response soap object

        result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        Log.e("Base64ToImage", result.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;

}
```

I am not able to figure out what exactly is the issue here.

Please help ! Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you check what `result .getPropertyCount();` is returning, maybe you are not getting any data?

Comment: @hrskrs but the exception which i am getting is on the line ` androidHttpTransport.call(
                "http://tempuri.org/IService/Base64ToImage", envelope);`  so there is nothing in the result object..

Comment: I think this is because of mismatching in content-type..plz check and also write an internet permission in the manifest if not.

Comment: @BornToWin so is this content type mismatch an error from android side or webservice side??

Comment: @shivani:I think from both,the type send from your client app and type received from your server.